# HttpClient not downloading the entire JSON

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone, dotnet-httpclient

I have an app on Windows Phone Store, it's a Feedly client and some of my users have been reporting an error for a while.
The error is a `JsonReaderException`: `Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'items[0].summary.content', line 1, position 702`

Looking at the error, it seems that the HttpClient didn't download the entire Json, since the position is the end of the response and the response seems incomplete.

Here is one of the responses:

```
{
    "id":"user/{userIdOmmited}/category/global.all",
    "updated":1417324466038,
    "continuation":"149ebfc5c13:c446de6:113fbbc6",
    "items": [{
        "id":"HBKNOlrSqigutJYKcZCnF5drtVL1uLeqMvamlHXyreE=_149ff1f0f76:213a17:34628bd3",
        "fingerprint":"eb0dc432",
        "originId":"https://medium.com/p/7948bfedb1bc",
        "updated":1417324463000,
        "title":"Iran’s Stealth Drone Claims Are Total BS",
        "published":1417324463000,"crawled":1417324466038,
        "alternate":[{
            "href":"https://medium.com/war-is-boring/irans-stealth-drone-claims-are-total-bs-7948bfedb1bc",
            "type":"text/html"
        }],
        "summary":{
            "content":"<div><p><a href=\"https://medium.com/war-is-boring/irans-stealth-drone-claims-are-total-bs-7948bfedb1bc\"><img height=\"200
```

This is the entire Json of one of the responses, as you can see it ends suddenly at the summary.content, that's why Json.Net can't deserialize it.

My Get method looks like this:

```
protected async Task<T> GetRequest<T>(string url)
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

    if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
        if (authentication != null)
            request.Headers.Authorization = authentication;
        var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data.EscapeJson());
    }
}
```

I pass the response DTO as a generics parameter to the method and it deserializes the Json.
The `EscapeJson` method in the return looks like this:

```
public static string EscapeJson(this string stringToEscape)
{
    return Regex.Replace(stringToEscape, @"(?<!\\)\\(?!"")(?!n)(?!\\)", @"\\", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
}
```

I've added this to try to solve the problem because I thought the problem was with the back slashes, but it wasn't (before I found out the json wasn't being downloaded completely).

I've been searching for a solution for this problem for a few weeks, and I couldn't come up with an answer.

In my research I found out that there is a parameter in the `SendAsync` that is the completionOption, which is an enum, `HttpCompletionOption`, that has two options: `ResponseContentRead` and `ResponseHeadersRead`.
The problem is that I don't know which one is the default and I don't know if changing this will solve the problem since I can't reproduce the problem myself, so I can't test it.

Does anyone has an idea of what might be the problem here?
Could it be a Timeout of sorts or this `HttpCompletionOption`?
I've been seeing the error for a while, searching for an answer and I have no clue on what might be going on.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I know this is old, but if you found a solution for this problem, it would help me very much!

Answer (score 0):

Make one HttpClient for the app to use. Do not dispose it. HttpClient is supposed to be reused and not disposed pr request. That is most likely the error.